# Vlookup against filtered data with VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

```
Sub FilteredTest()

    Dim LastRow1 As Long
    Dim LastRow2 As Long
    Dim myI As Long
    Dim myLookupvalue As Long
    Dim myTableArray As Range

    LastRow1 = Worksheets(2).Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow2 = Worksheets(8).Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set myTableArray = Worksheets(2).Range("A2:A" & LastRow1)

    myI = 3

    Do Until myI > LastRow2

        myLookupvalue = Worksheets(8).Range("E" & myI)
        On Error Resume Next
        Worksheets(8).Range("H" & myI).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(myLookupvalue, myTableArray, 1, False)
        ' Error 1004 is when the VLOOKUP can't find a corresponding value
        If Err = 1004 Then
            Worksheets(8).Range("H" & myI).Value = "Remove"
        End If
        myI = myI + 1

    Loop
End Sub
```

I need some help getting this code to only Vlookup against visible values in another sheet.

Basically what I want to do, is have column *H#* in the main sheet lookup values in column *A* in another data-sheet and give a regular Iferror w/ Vlookup output in column *E#* at the main sheet.

I've tried several placements of the *SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)*-function both outside the loop and inside the loop, but nothing I do seems to work. All I get are Errors in the code or errors on the Vlookup.
I've tried searching on this site and googling like a madman. Threw in the towel at this point and decided to start a thread on my own. Hope someone can help me integrate the function to my code and/or help me understand this function better.

Comment: You would be better off using a dictionary: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 39 - Dictionaries](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=dND4coLI_B8&index=43&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: `.usedrange.specialcells(xlcelltypevisible)` will give you the range, so `.usedrange.specialcells(xlcelltypevisible).address` for example will give you the filtered rows etc, i got `$A$1:$K$1,$A$16228:$K$16230` in my tests

Answer (score 0):

You might add this User Defined Function and swap out WorksheetFunction.VLookup for this new 'helper' function.

```
Option Explicit

Function VisLookup(lu As Variant, rng As Range, col As Long, _
                   Optional bin As Boolean = False) As Variant

    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange)
    VisLookup = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    If col > rng.Columns.Count Then Exit Function

    If bin Then

        For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
            If rng.Cells(i + 1, "A").Value2 > lu And Not rng.Rows(i).Hidden Then
                VisLookup = rng.Cells(i, col).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

    Else

        For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
            If lu = rng.Cells(i, "A").Value2 And Not rng.Rows(i).Hidden Then
                VisLookup = rng.Cells(i, col).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

    End If

End Function
```

Implemented as,

```
Worksheets(8).Range("H" & myI).Value = VisLookup(myLookupvalue, myTableArray, 1, False)
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. This worked, thank you very much! However, it is rather slow - it has to lookup around 10-11k rows of data which will take a lot of time. Is there any way to make this process faster while still maintaining automation?